# Read a line with default input in zsh

Tags: zsh, line-editor

This function can be used to help user input a modification of some text.

```
 function change { bash -c "read -ei \"$1\" temp && echo \$temp" }
```

What is idiomatic zsh way to do something similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the [`vared`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-vared) builtin.

```
change () {
  local temp=$1
  vared temp
  print -lr -- $temp
}
```

And if you want to use the string entered by the user later in your script, it's just

```
temp='initial value'
vared temp
```